# How to write xml schema for this xml file

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
  <ConnectionConfig>
      <Machine Ip="192.168.0.7">
          <ConnectionString>Data Source=TWO;Initial Catalog=Freight;User ID=sa;Password=f5tech</ConnectionString>
      </Machine>
    </ConnectionConfig>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) utility. Save this to a xml file and:

```
xsd.exe test.xml
```

This will infer the schema from the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Microsoft XML to Schema Tool for Visual Basic 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb840042.aspx)